# Glossy material problem

Tags: materials

I have a problem with glossy material. I have in a scene a glossy plane, with a cube and two spheres like in the following image. I set the cube not to be mirrored on the plane.

[image]

What should I do in order to have displayed the spheres in the glossy plane only when it rolls off the cube, meaning to have some sort of realism.

Thank you very much for any advice. Have a very nice day.

Comment: you mean that there's (almost) no reflection of the spheres, when they are on top of the cube and when they get closer, the reflection becomes more visible?

Comment: I mean, in this image the green sphere reflection shouldn't be visible because it's obstructed by the cube. If the green sphere would roll and fall off the cube on the glossy plane object, it should have the reflection.

Comment: Can you add your .blend file? (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Here it is: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2261" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2261/)

Comment: But if you set the cube not to be mirrored this is the realistic result. I don't understand what you're trying to make.